# aws lambda, ask_sdk_core module not importing

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit, python-module

The **ask_sdk_core** is included in the **requirements.txt** file of my lambda function.  However, the **ask_sdk_core** does not import when I run the actual function.
I am following the cake walk sample found at 
`https://github.com/alexa/skill-sample-python-first-skill/tree/master/module-1`
but am trying to make the lambda on my personal AWS account instead of the alexa-hosted lambda.

When i point to the Alexa skill to the alexa-hosted skill the skill runs as expected but when pointing to the lambda that i made by copying the code from the alexa skill kit the lambda function does not return any results.

Photos included of lambda on personal AWS account.
I have attempted changing multiple values of the names of the different functions but nothing is seeming to work.

[image: Lambda in Console]
[image: Lambda in Console 2]

lambda execution results:

```
Response:
{
  "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'ask_sdk_core'",
  "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError"
}

Request ID:
"7f220b6d-49e4-4fbe-99b5-e5cc1d9c129a"

Function Logs:
START RequestId: 7f220b6d-49e4-4fbe-99b5-e5cc1d9c129a Version: $LATEST
[ERROR] Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'ask_sdk_core'END RequestId: 7f220b6d-49e4-4fbe-99b5-e5cc1d9c129a
REPORT RequestId: 7f220b6d-49e4-4fbe-99b5-e5cc1d9c129a  Duration: 11.39 ms  Billed Duration: 100 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 57 MB
```

requirements.txt:

```
ask-sdk-core
ask-sdk-s3-persistence-adapter
pytz
```

lambda_function.py code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# This sample demonstrates handling intents from an Alexa skill using the Alexa Skills Kit SDK for Python.
# Please visit https://alexa.design/cookbook for additional examples on implementing slots, dialog management,
# session persistence, api calls, and more.
# This sample is built using the handler classes approach in skill builder.
import logging
import ask_sdk_core.utils as ask_utils

from ask_sdk_core.skill_builder import SkillBuilder
from ask_sdk_core.dispatch_components import AbstractRequestHandler
from ask_sdk_core.dispatch_components import AbstractExceptionHandler
from ask_sdk_core.handler_input import HandlerInput

from ask_sdk_model import Response

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)


class LaunchRequestHandler(AbstractRequestHandler):
    """Handler for Skill Launch."""
    def can_handle(self, handler_input):
        # type: (HandlerInput) -> bool

        return ask_utils.is_request_type("LaunchRequest")(handler_input)

    def handle(self, handler_input):
        # type: (HandlerInput) -> Response
        speak_output = "Hello! Welcome to cake walk. That was a piece of cake! Bye!"

        return (
            handler_input.response_builder
                .speak(speak_output)
                #.ask(speak_output)
                .response
        )


class HelloWorldIntentHandler(AbstractRequestHandler):
    """Handler for Hello World Intent."""
    def can_handle(self, handler_input):
        # type: (HandlerInput) -> bool
        return ask_utils.is_intent_name("HelloWorldIntent")(handler_input)

    def handle(self, handler_input):
        # type: (HandlerInput) -> Response
        speak_output = "Hello World!"

        return (
            handler_input.response_builder
                .speak(speak_output)
                # .ask("add a reprompt if you want to keep the session open for the user to respond")
                .response
        )


class HelpIntentHandler(AbstractRequestHandler):
    """Handler for Help Intent."""
    def can_handle(self, handler_input):
        # type: (HandlerInput) -> bool
        return ask_utils.is_intent_name("AMAZON.HelpIntent")(handler_input)

    def handle(self, handler_input):
        # type: (HandlerInput) -> Response
        speak_output = "You can say hello to me! How can I help?"

        return (
            handler_input.response_builder
                .speak(speak_output)
                .ask(speak_output)
                .response
        )


class CancelOrStopIntentHandler(AbstractRequestHandler):
    """Single handler for Cancel and Stop Intent."""
    def can_handle(self, handler_input):
        # type: (HandlerInput) -> bool
        return (ask_utils.is_intent_name("AMAZON.CancelIntent")(handler_input) or
                ask_utils.is_intent_name("AMAZON.StopIntent")(handler_input))

    def handle(self, handler_input):
        # type: (HandlerInput) -> Response
        speak_output = "Goodbye!"

        return (
            handler_input.response_builder
                .speak(speak_output)
                .response
        )


class SessionEndedRequestHandler(AbstractRequestHandler):
    """Handler for Session End."""
    def can_handle(self, handler_input):
        # type: (HandlerInput) -> bool
        return ask_utils.is_request_type("SessionEndedRequest")(handler_input)

    def handle(self, handler_input):
        # type: (HandlerInput) -> Response

        # Any cleanup logic goes here.

        return handler_input.response_builder.response


class IntentReflectorHandler(AbstractRequestHandler):
    """The intent reflector is used for interaction model testing and debugging.
    It will simply repeat the intent the user said. You can create custom handlers
    for your intents by defining them above, then also adding them to the request
    handler chain below.
    """
    def can_handle(self, handler_input):
        # type: (HandlerInput) -> bool
        return ask_utils.is_request_type("IntentRequest")(handler_input)

    def handle(self, handler_input):
        # type: (HandlerInput) -> Response
        intent_name = ask_utils.get_intent_name(handler_input)
        speak_output = "You just triggered " + intent_name + "."

        return (
            handler_input.response_builder
                .speak(speak_output)
                # .ask("add a reprompt if you want to keep the session open for the user to respond")
                .response
        )


class CatchAllExceptionHandler(AbstractExceptionHandler):
    """Generic error handling to capture any syntax or routing errors. If you receive an error
    stating the request handler chain is not found, you have not implemented a handler for
    the intent being invoked or included it in the skill builder below.
    """
    def can_handle(self, handler_input, exception):
        # type: (HandlerInput, Exception) -> bool
        return True

    def handle(self, handler_input, exception):
        # type: (HandlerInput, Exception) -> Response
        logger.error(exception, exc_info=True)

        speak_output = "Sorry, I had trouble doing what you asked. Please try again."

        return (
            handler_input.response_builder
                .speak(speak_output)
                .ask(speak_output)
                .response
        )

# The SkillBuilder object acts as the entry point for your skill, routing all request and response
# payloads to the handlers above. Make sure any new handlers or interceptors you've
# defined are included below. The order matters - they're processed top to bottom.


sb = SkillBuilder()

sb.add_request_handler(LaunchRequestHandler())
sb.add_request_handler(HelloWorldIntentHandler())
sb.add_request_handler(HelpIntentHandler())
sb.add_request_handler(CancelOrStopIntentHandler())
sb.add_request_handler(SessionEndedRequestHandler())
sb.add_request_handler(IntentReflectorHandler()) # make sure IntentReflectorHandler is last so it doesn't override your custom intent handlers

sb.add_exception_handler(CatchAllExceptionHandler())

lambda_handler = sb.lambda_handler()
```

Comment: Have you bundled `ask_sdk_core` with the lambda deployment package? From screenshots I don't see it there.

Comment: I'm not sure how you would do that? i am not very familiar with this all and am just trying to follow the guide i found online.  Do you know where i could look to see how to do this bundling you are talking about?

Comment: So i am clear, i am not using a zip file to create the lambda.  I am just creating it from scratch.

Comment: @kevinlowenhaupt did you find a solution to it?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing `pip install -r requirements.txt` to install the libraries before creating the deployment package?

The X-Ray SDK isn't a part of the underlying environment for the function and [needs to be compiled](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/xray-sdk-python.html) either as a deployment package or as a layer. Layers provide modularity with libraries which are often shared amongst other functions. In either of the cases, you would have to install the modules using the Amazon Linux AMI listed [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-runtimes.html) for the runtime used.

A quick difference in the folder structure amongst deployment package and layers -

1. Deployment package: Required modules must be present in the root directory of the .zip
2. Layers: Modules must be added in the `/python` or `python/lib/pythonX.X/site-packages`

`zipinfo filename.zip` is really helpful to peek into the folder structure without unpacking the .zip.

Comment: i'm sorry im trying to follow what you commented.  I am not using a zip for the lambda and have instead created it from scratch.  Are you saying i just need to put '''pip install requirements.txt''' into the code somewhere?

Comment: Without the deployment package or Lambda layer, it will not work, as these libraries need to be packaged inside a .zip file which then needs to be uploaded to the function. See this example with a sample module 'pillow' added as a deployment package: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-package.html#python-package-dependencies

```pip install -r requirements.txt``` needs to be compiled from your local machine (EC2 with Lambda AMI is the recommended way)

Answer (score 0):

just use a lambda layer, you may create it yourself but use this one:
`arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:173334852312:layer:ask-sdk-for-python-36:1`

Answer (score -1):

I'm using **Python 3.8** in **Windows10**:

Run powershell as admin.

Choose current working dir as: C:\

```
mkdir pythonimport
chdir pythonimport
py -3 -m venv venv
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Force
C:\pythonimport\venv> .\Scripts\Activate.ps1
(venv) PS C:\pythonimport\venv> pip install ask_sdk_core
```

Once this is done, you'll find all the required packages downloaded.

Now Goto:

```
C:\pythonimport\venv\Lib\site-packages
```

Here you'll find all the new downloaded packages like **ask_sdk_core, ask_sdk_model** and **ask_sdk_runtime.**

Now copy the code snippet from lambda page i.e. from ***lambda_function.py***

Then create a new python file in

```
C:\pythonimport\venv\Lib\site-packages\lambda_function.py
```

and paste the same code snippet.

Now zip the below mentioned files as **lambda_function.zip**.

- ask_sdk_core
- ask_sdk_model
- ask_sdk_runtime
- lambda_function.py

Now, in Lambda service web page, upload the zip file.

Voila!!

It will work like a charm :-)

If you've any concern please drop a line.

*PS: Use Dummy test case to check the exceptions raised.*